# Magento 2.4.2 cacheable search results (past first page)

Tags: magento2, search, varnish

We have seen that Magento after first page (whenever there is a p request parameter) the code forcibly makes the page un-cacheable.

Is there a reason for allowing the first page to be cached and not the rest?

The code in \Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index:105-11 removes the "q" parameter and then if it sees any other parameter it flags the results as non-cachable.

We wish to enable caching in search results (all pages) but wish to be sure it wont break anything.

(we use varnish)

Comment: Could you please share your VCL and some examples of URLs containing `q` or `p` parameters. That will allow me to give you better advice.

Comment: The code itself makes the pages non-cacheable not VCL. We have checked it. The code reference is supplied.